# No suitable method found to override C# MonoDroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

> 'CMS_Template.PictureCallback.OnPictureTaken(byte[],
>   Android.Hardware.Camera)' is marked as an override but no suitable
>   method found to override.

I'm trying to get my own OnPictureTaken working, but I'm getting the above error. I'm passing PictureCallback as an argument to Camera.TakePicture.

My code:

```
public class PictureCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Hardware.Camera.IPictureCallback 
{
    public override void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OnPictureTaken called.");
    }
}
```

IPictureCallback.OnPictureTaken method:

```
public void OnPictureTaken (byte[] data, Camera camera)
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an override because it is implementing a method signature in an interface rather than overriding a method in a parent class. Just take the override keyword out.